# Identifying rectangular ducts and their inside information using Python

Tags: python, image, pdf, python-tesseract

Click to see floor plan image:

[image: click to see floor plan image]

I'm a mechanical engineer and new to programming.

I want to identify the different color rectangular ducts and information enclosed in them.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I've tried extracting the text using `tesseract`.

Comment: I know of no OCR engine that can recognize colors. And very few engines are capable of recognizing vector graphics (i.e. lines, rectangles). Are you sure you are dealing with a PDF with scanned images? As an engineer, it is more probable that you are dealing with PDF output of CAD/CAM - which regularly produces vector graphics.

Comment: yes you are right, i've pdf and i converted it to image.
Would it be better to use only pdf and do the further processing?

Comment: Yes, of course! Working with image-pages always is a lot more difficult and imprecise! Effectively, conversion to image **_looses_** information - unnecesarily.

Comment: This page is a mixture of text and colored vector graphics it seems. You can use PyMuPDF to extract all this information - but it will be a challenging task (for the graphics only - text is trivial. **Note:** I am a maintainer and the original creator of [PyMuPDF](https://pypi.org/project/PyMuPDF/). You can join us on [Discord](https://discord.gg/AKAETrQc) for an easier communication and exchange of PDF examples.

Comment: Hi @JorjMcKie, i've joined the discord channel and have put the issue there. Thanks.

Comment: It is able to identify the rectangles but no texts inside them are getting printed.

Comment: For those interested, join the [Discord](https://discord.gg/AKAETrQc) channel to see a solution script for this problem using PyMuPDF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is first simple script that extracts vector graphics having a non-black border and any text inside them.

```py
import fitz  # PyMuPDF
doc = fitz.open("input.pdf")
page = doc[0]  # first page (0-based numbering scheme)
paths = page.get_drawings()  # extract all vector graphics (list of dictionaries)
for path in paths:
    if path["color"] is None or path["color"] == (0,0,0)
        # ignore borderless graphics and black border
        continue
    print(f"border color {p['color']}")
    text = page.get_text(clip=path["rect"])  # extract any text inside
    print(f"text inside {p['rect']: {text}")
```

**Note:** I am a maintainer and the original creator of [PyMuPDF](https://pypi.org/project/PyMuPDF/).